# Django save history of get request

Tags: django, forms, post, get

im developing a django app in which people enter their ID and they get either their active customer or not.

that has already been solved, what i want is to save everytime a person trys to enter their ID

this is the view:

```
def ingreso_cliente(request):
query_string = ''
found_entries = None
activo = None
#sin buscar
retorno = '3'
today=datetime.now

if ('idcliente' in request.GET) and request.GET['idcliente'].strip():
    #filtro por el usuario
    query_string = request.GET['idcliente']
    entry_query = get_query(query_string, ['cliente__ci'])
    #filtro por el mes
    found_entries = Pagos.objects.filter(entry_query).order_by('cliente__ci')

    activo = found_entries.filter(Q(mes_desde__lte=today)&Q(mes_hasta__gte=today))
    if (not activo):
        #deudor
        retorno = '2'
    else:
        #activo
        retorno = '1'



return render_to_response('ingreso_cliente.html', { 'retorno':retorno, 'today':today }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this is the template i use to enter the client ID and i get if he is active or not:

```
<form method="get" action="/home/ingreso_cliente/">
<input type="text" name="idcliente" id="idcliente"/>
<input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
</form>

hora: {{today}}

{% if retorno == '1' %}
    <span>Cliente Activo</span>
{% elif retorno == '2'%}
    <span>Cliente Deudor</span>
{% endif %}
```

its a get request, and to save in the db I need a POST, but with a POST i can not get the data from the db to know either its active or not. is there any way of doing this?

Comment: why can't you save something in a GET request? you can perfectly well create/save objects towards the end of your view.

Comment: PS. You can also get the user from the DB if you submit the form via POST - makes no difference for the view

Comment: i did not know i could save with a GET, how should i do that?

Comment: i tryed to get the user  with the POST but nothing comes out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference if you submit your form via GET or POST.

At the end of your view (shortly before the `return`), do something like:

```
LoginAttempt.objects.create(username=query_string, active=retorno)
```

where `LoginAttempt` is a model saving login attempts. This is not ideal but you get the idea, can use the `logging` interface instead or whatever you want to log the attempts.

PS. Your form will work perfectly fine with POST too, but obviously then you'll need to look for your `idcliente` value in `request.POST` not `request.GET`